# How to test synchronization process with positive & negative test case and test scenario?

Tags: manual-testing

I am using one database synchronization from one platform (php) to another platform (sharepoit) l, but I am confused for which conditions check for synchronization process. which steps follows for test synchronization process.

Comment: Please provide more details. I feel it is bit broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Key points in testing any kind of synchronised process which may help you design good test cases are:

1. More than 1 requests are trying to access the same resource.
2. First come should be served first (unless something very bad happened to it e.g. the thread is killed)

So for example, try to make some requests at the same time, then cancel/abort the leader and see which one is processed next. Also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825657/how-to-unit-test-synchronized-code